# Macbook pro 13'' (early 2011) battery not charging/suddenly shutting down

Tags: macbook-pro, charging, power

I have a Macbook Pro 13" early 2011 which stopped charging a couple of months ago. I'll describe its current issues:

**1)** Not charging battery

**2)** If turned on it can either not start (right white light flashes fast) or start for a couple of minutes and then shut down.

**I could start it with this method:**

> ```
> - remove power cord
> - Pressing power for 10 seconds
> - plug power cord, wait 10 seconds
> - release power.
> ```

When I perform these steps, fan runs at maximum power (6000+ rpm) and the green light in the power cord is off. Also, mac fans control application didn't detect the fans.

I tried to reset the SMC with shift+option+ctrl+power before starting it.

Is there something I can do or some step i'm doing wrong?

**NOTE:** I'm currently living in a country without apple support

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What is the cycle count? You will find this is System Information, under "Power". (You can bring up the System Information app by holding Alt/Opt and clicking on the Apple menu, where it will be the first item.)

You will be lucky for a battery (of that era) to last between 3 and 5 years. Assuming you've not had it replaced before, and it's 10 years old, then it's just a completely dead battery.

If there are no Apple Authorised Repair centers where you are, then you can try to do it yourself, if you can find a replacement part. (A site like eBay will probably sell them, though the quality may be hard to determine.)

https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Early+2011+Battery+Replacement/5116